# How to implement MenuStrip functions?

Tags: vb.net, copy, paste

I have a `MenuStrip` control and when I right clicked on it and selected "insert standard items", it created a few functions. There are a few options there that I would like to get working: Cut, Copy, Paste, Delete, and Select All. I presume that for what I want, I'd need to make my own classes for each function. (ie: Cut class, Copy class... etc.) I would like to be able to do something similar to the example below:

```
ActiveControl.Text.CutTo(Source)

ActiveControl.Text.CopyTo(Source)

ActiveControl.Text.Delete()

ActiveControl.Text.Select.All()

ActiveControl.Text.PasteFrom(Source)
```

Im doing this in Vb.net On Windows 7 . Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Managing Cut, Copy Paste button availability .NET WinForms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988721/managing-cut-copy-paste-button-availability-net-winforms)

Answer (score 1):

Just double click the the MenuItem that you and it will create the Click event subroutine for you.
You will need to implement the logic yourself.

You can look at this MSDN Forum [Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/4654a0e3-bb68-494e-a1f2-03884a72f7d6), this [article](http://thedailyreviewer.com/dotnet/view/copy-cut-and-paste-102143119) and this [CodeProject Article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/clipboard01.aspx) they all discuss using the clipboard object for doing cut and paste.

Comment: The actual implementation will depend on what ActiveControl is.

Comment: well consider the functions im trying to make; (Select all, delete, cut, copy and paste) what active control could apply to all of these? (it should be quite obvious)